# Materialize CSS Sidebar

Tags: css, materialize

i am new on materialize css and iam stuck on creating side bar between navbar and footer.
this is what i get when i use the sidebar
[image]

this is what i would like to achieve
[image]

thank you for your help

Comment: share your code here! or create snippet

Comment: sorry! here is the code : https://codepen.io/greents/pen/XWgLaoq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add to the sidebar menu a `top` attribute with the same pixels as top navbar height (64px in that case).

And after that you may add a calculated height substracting 100% with the previously implemented `top` pixels (64px) + the footer height (50px), the result is 114px

```
.sidenav.sidenav-fixed{
    left: 0;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
    transform: translateX(0);
    position: fixed;
    top: 64px;
    height: calc(100% - 114px);
   
}
```